# C# generic interface type inference question

Tags: c#, generics, types, inference

I'm not sure how to phrase this question concisely without just giving the example so here goes:

```
public interface IThing<T>
{
    void Do(T obj);
}

public class ThingOne : IThing<int>
{
    public void Do(int obj)
    {
    }
}

public class ThingTwo : IThing<string>
{
    public void Do(string obj)
    {
    }
}

public class ThingFactory
{
    public IThing<T> Create<T>(string param)
    {
        if (param.Equals("one"))
            return (IThing<T>)new ThingOne();

        if (param.Equals("two"))
            return (IThing<T>)new ThingTwo();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = new ThingFactory();

        // any way we can get the compiler to infer IThing<int> ?
        var thing = f.Create("one");

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not type-inference - your return type isn't static, i.e. it is not known in advance whether TypeOne or TypeTwo will be returned.

Comment: Adding to answers, your code should not be even compilable without that type "inference" because of `Create<T>` method and especially because of your castings. `new ThingTwo()` cannot be casted to `IThing<T>`, the same is correct for `ThingOne`. It looks like you need a dynamically typed language. Or you have made (going to make) an error in your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this because the result of your `Create` factory method will be evaluated at runtime based on the value of the parameter. Generics are for compile-time safety and in your case you cannot have such safety because the parameter value will be known only at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The question appears to be here:

```
// any way we can get the compiler to infer IThing<int> ?
var thing = f.Create("one");
```

No.  You would need to explicitly specify the type:

```
var thing = f.Create<int>("one");
```

You can't infer the return type without having a parameter used specifically in the method.  The compiler uses the parameters passed to the method to infer the type `T`, and in this case, it's a single string parameter, with no parameters of type `T`.  As such, there's no way to have this inferred for you.